# Problems installing grunt: Multiple dependency issues

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, package.json

I keep getting all of these warnings and dependency issues when trying to install grunt locally using `npm install grunt --save-dev`.

```
PS C:\atomworkspace\angularProject\conFusion> npm install grunt --save-dev
conFusion@ C:\atomworkspace\angularProject\conFusion
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@1.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-clean@1.0.0 extraneous
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-coffee@~0.10.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-compass@~0.7.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-compress@~0.8.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-concat@~0.4.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-connect@~0.7.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-copy@~0.5.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-csslint@~0.2.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-cssmin@~0.9.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-handlebars@~0.8.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-htmlmin@~0.2.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-imagemin@~0.7.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-jade@~0.11.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-jasmine@~0.6.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-jshint@1.1.0 extraneous
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-jst@~0.6.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-less@~0.11.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-nodeunit@~0.3.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-qunit@~0.4.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-requirejs@~0.4.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-sass@~0.7.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-stylus@~0.15.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-symlink@~0.3.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-uglify@~0.4.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-watch@~0.6.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt-contrib-yuidoc@~0.5.0
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-clean@~0.5.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-coffee@~0.10.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-compass@~0.7.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-compress@~0.8.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-concat@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-connect@~0.7.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-copy@~0.5.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-csslint@~0.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-cssmin@~0.9.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-handlebars@~0.8.0 but none was installe
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-htmlmin@~0.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-imagemin@~0.7.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-jade@~0.11.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-jasmine@~0.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-jshint@~0.10.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-jst@~0.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-less@~0.11.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-nodeunit@~0.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-qunit@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-requirejs@~0.4.1 but none was installed
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-sass@~0.7.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-stylus@~0.15.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-symlink@~0.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-uglify@~0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-watch@~0.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib@0.11.0 requires a peer of grunt-contrib-yuidoc@~0.5.0 but none was installed.

PS C:\atomworkspace\angularProject\conFusion>
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "conFusion",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": { "grunt": "^1.0.1" },
    "engines": { "node": ">=0.10.0" }
}
```

Comment: Here's my package.json:

{
  "name": "conFusion",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}

Comment: They are *warnings*. You have a bunch of Grunt plugins that have peer dependencies on an older version of Grunt. Until the plugins are updated, there's not much you can do. However, things should work anyway ... maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing grunt globally `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: FYI, it should be `grunt-cli` that's installed globally: `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade npm version to 6.x. It should fix the issue. npm v7 throws these kind of errors.